# Dynamic table shortcode wordpress

Tags: wordpress, dynamic, html-table, shortcode

Are there any solutions to create a table `<tr><td></td></tr>` shortcode in wordpress without repeating the `<tr><td></td></tr>` on backend. Like this?

```
add_shortcode( 'final_table', 'final_table_output');
    function final_table_output( $attr) {
    return '
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>id</th>
                <th>name</th>
                <th>email</th>
                <th>ages</th>
                <th>gender</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>' . $attr['id'] . '</td>
                <td>' . $attr['name'] . '</td>
                <td>' . $attr['email'] . '</td>
                <td>' . $attr['ages'] . '</td>
                <td>' . $attr['gender'] . '</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        ';
};
```

And in post will be:

```
[final_table id="1" name="john" email="john@gmail.com" ages="21" gender="male"]
[final_table id="2" name="leo" email="leo@yahoo.com" ages="19" gender="male"]
[final_table id="3" name="tina" email="tina@gmail.com" ages="21" gender="female"]
```

And should it inject the rows?

Comment: Don't try and write this yourself: there's a plugin called "table maker" that makes this EASY to do.

Answer (score 0):

Reference here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode

```
function final_table_func( $atts ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => '',
        'name' => '',
        'email' => '',
        'ages' => '',
        'gender' => ''
    ), $atts, 'final_table' );

    return '
        <tr>
            <td>' . $atts['id'] . '</td>
            <td>' . $atts['name'] . '</td>
            <td>' . $atts['email'] . '</td>
            <td>' . $atts['ages'] . '</td>
            <td>' . $atts['gender'] . '</td>
        </tr>
    ';
}
add_shortcode( 'final_table', 'final_table_func' );
```

Then, you can do the shortcode you describe above.

**EDIT:** I modified it so it will only return table rows. I would suggest further modifying this so that your table and table headers are created within this shortcode, but with the way your original question and comment is suggesting, you will need to add the HTML for the table and table headers within the source code on the page itself.

This is not the ideal way of doing this and I would go about this a different way, but I'm answering your original question/comment.

Comment: Chris Gleason, Thank you so much for the quick answer. but it does not create the new rows but new table. i just curious how to inject a new rows without creating hole new table. :(